# export mysql data to excel from Java using Apache POI

Tags: java, mysql, excel, apache-poi

I have the class `MysqlToXls` copied from here:
http://mikescode.wordpress.com/2008/02/16/exporting-a-mysql-table-to-excel-xls-in-java/

I edited the class making a constructor that doesn't need any parameter in this way:

```
public MysqlToXls()
throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    // Create MySQL database connection
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Spinning?user=root&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8";
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
}
```

While there is not any guide I try to do myself and I'm not able.

```
  MysqlToXls m=new MysqlToXls();
  m.generateXls("utente", "utenti.xls");
```

But there are no errors and the file utenti.xls remains blank.
Does someone know where is the problem?

Comment: Do you have any data in the table `utente`? Does the `ResultSet` in `generateXls()` contain any results?

Comment: yes I have data and the rs is not empty..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only problem was the path of the file. I was trying to save the file in one folder of the project (with a relative path), while if I give the absolute path (f.e. on the desktop) it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you have to explicitly close the outputStream, so insted of doing this:

```
xlsWorkbook.write(new FileOutputStream(filename));
```

you should try to do something like this:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
xlsWorkbook.write(fos);
fos.close();
```

Comment: Actually I tried the linked code and it worked like a charm. So closing the output stream will not resolve your problem.

Comment: Yes, no problem at all with the original code. Sorry, I have no clue.